# How to get the list of all incoming intermediate vertices between a source vertex and target vertex of specific label using Gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin

The Gremlin query that I use to get the list of all outgoing vertices (with edge label “has”) from a selected vertex “P1” until it reaches the vertex with specific label “L3” is this:

```
g.V().has("id”,”P1”).repeat(out(“has”)).until(hasLabel(“L3”)).path().by("id")
```

As expected, the query above returns me the list of all intermediate nodes between selected vertex and target vertex labeled “L3”.

However, when using the same query (changing the ‘out’ to ‘in’) in opposite direction, i.e., to get the list of all incoming vertices from a selected vertex to the target vertex with specific label, i get a gremlin query error straight away.

Here is the query:

```
 g.V().has("id”,”P3”).repeat(in(“has”)).until(hasLabel(“L1”)).path().by("id")
```

The error looks like this:

```
Failure in submitting query: 
Error: Script compile error: Missing ')'
```

I don’t see any missing brackets in the query though and the only change between the queries for incoming or outgoing vertices i made is using ‘in’ instead of ‘out’.

In the official tinkerpop documentation (https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.9/reference/#_traversal_strategies_2), in traversal strategies, I cannot find any example with repeat(in()), only with repeat(out()). Is there a special query or method to get all the incoming vertices from a selected vertex until it reaches the vertex with a specific label?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem or not, but I could see where you would get an error because "in" is a reserved word in Groovy so, you have to explicitly spawn it using the anonymous traversal class with: `__.in()`, therefore:

```
g.V().has("id","P3").repeat(__.in("has")).until(hasLabel("L1")).path().by("id")
```

This issue is documented in a number of places in the Reference Documentation, but perhaps you missed it (you referenced a fairly old version of the documentation as well) - described here in a NOTE in the [Vertex Steps](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-steps) for example.